# Missing annotations.jar

Tags: android, annotations, revision

I am trying to update my Android SDK Tools to 17 rev. and I updated usign SDK Tools but in Properties/library ;[image]

But the fact that in the support folder there is a annotations.jar already. 
What should I do to fix it?

Comment: Solution (Gradle) -  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16690914/importing-notnull-or-nullable-and-android-studio-wont-compile

Answer (score 33, accepted):

I had the same problem. I went to the SDK Manager within eclipse (Window --> Android SDK Manager) and installed the Android Support package which is found in the Extras folder. After the install the error was gone (at least in my system)

Comment: the rar is located at \android-sdk-windows\tools\support

Comment: You may need to refresh your project (right-click in the Package Explorer and select Refresh - or, select the project and press F5)

Answer (score 34):

So, when i updated sdk to L version i had same problem. But after Extra folders updating in SDK Manager i didn't find annotation.jar file. Maybe Google bug with new SDK version. So i copied annotation.jar file from old SDK folder (folder half a year ago)

Comment: I went back to an un-updated sdk version to resolve this issue in my eclipse android projects.

Comment: cant find the damn file anywhere after update. No old copy of sdk available.

Comment: @xaragen download annotations from here: http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.google.android/annotations/4.1.1.4
Rename it to just annotations, and place it in the support directory.

Comment: same issues emma jars

Comment: It is confirmed by Google that SDK Tools r23 & Platform-tools r20 (L preview release) are indeed missing annotations.jar, proguard & hprof. Workaround here: https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=72419#c12

Answer (score 19):

Right click onto your project, in context menu choose Properties, your will see a window.
Second line is Android - click onto it.
You will see list of installed SDK.
Check any SDK which has API level 16 or more.

annotationas.jar is embedded in SDK of 16 API level and after it.

Comment: This had no effect for me.

Comment: Works for me. Looks like that's the correct solution.

Comment: Luke, please check if you have API 16 installed

Comment: +1 Great this worked for me.  But that makes it impossible to build to a lower level API target.

Answer (score 6):

What worked for me was downloading the annotations.jar file, and then adding that to where it was supposed to be according to the error.

It can be downloaded here: http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.google.android/annotations/4.1.1.4

Answer (score 3):

After updating all of the packages in the SDK manager you may need to update Android Developer toolkit also. *Eclipse* -> *Help* -> *Check Updates* -> *Install*

Answer (score 2):

I think Google has changed the location of that jar file from `<SDK_DIR>/extras/android/support/annotations.jar` to `<SDK_DIR>/extras/android/support/annotations/android-support-annotations.jar`

To solve this issue, I followed these steps on all projects and libraries in my workspace using this jar:

- Just removed the file from `Java Build Path -> Libray` Tab,
- then `Add External Jars`
- Chose file from the given location above.

Answer (score 1):

I had this issue just now, and this was the top result in Google.  Posting my results for time-traveling Googlers from the future.

Jose's solution didn't work for me, as there was no "Extras" folder, nor "Android Support" package, in my update manager, so things must have changed within the past two years.

Here's what did work for me: **update *all* of the packages in the SDK manager.**  I don't know which update in particular fixed it, but now that they are all up-to-date, the problem is solved.