# when I run my twitter application in android I got following error

Tags: android

Please help me How I can resolved this problem.

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: already added: Ltwitter4j/Annotation;
[2012-05-14 10:40:59 - Twitter] Dx  at com.android.dx.dex.file.ClassDefsSection.add(ClassDefsSection.java:123)
[2012-05-14 10:40:59 - Twitter] Dx  at com.android.dx.dex.file.DexFile.add(DexFile.java:163)
[2012-05-14 10:40:59 - Twitter] Dx  at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.processClass(Main.java:486)
[2012-05-14 10:40:59 - Twitter] Dx  at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.processFileBytes(Main.java:455)
[2012-05-14 10:40:59 - Twitter] Dx  at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.access$400(Main.java:67)
[2012-05-14 10:40:59 - Twitter] Dx  at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main$1.processFileBytes(Main.java:394)
[2012-05-14 10:40:59 - Twitter] Dx  at com.android.dx.cf.direct.ClassPathOpener.processArchive(ClassPathOpener.java:245)
[2012-05-14 10:40:59 - Twitter] Dx  at com.android.dx.cf.direct.ClassPathOpener.processOne(ClassPathOpener.java:131)
[2012-05-14 10:40:59 - Twitter] Dx  at com.android.dx.cf.direct.ClassPathOpener.process(ClassPathOpener.java:109)
[2012-05-14 10:40:59 - Twitter] Dx  at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.processOne(Main.java:418)
[2012-05-14 10:40:59 - Twitter] Dx  at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.processAllFiles(Main.java:329)
[2012-05-14 10:40:59 - Twitter] Dx  at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.run(Main.java:206)
[2012-05-14 10:40:59 - Twitter] Dx  at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
[2012-05-14 10:40:59 - Twitter] Dx  at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
[2012-05-14 10:40:59 - Twitter] Dx  at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
[2012-05-14 10:40:59 - Twitter] Dx  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:616)
[2012-05-14 10:40:59 - Twitter] Dx  at com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.build.DexWrapper.run(DexWrapper.java:180)
[2012-05-14 10:40:59 - Twitter] Dx  at com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.build.BuildHelper.executeDx(BuildHelper.java:702)
[2012-05-14 10:40:59 - Twitter] Dx  at com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.build.builders.PostCompilerBuilder.build(PostCompilerBuilder.java:646)
[2012-05-14 10:40:59 - Twitter] Dx  at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.BuildManager$2.run(BuildManager.java:728)
[2012-05-14 10:40:59 - Twitter] Dx  at org.eclipse.core.runtime.SafeRunner.run(SafeRunner.java:42)
[2012-05-14 10:40:59 - Twitter] Dx  at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.BuildManager.basicBuild(BuildManager.java:199)
[2012-05-14 10:40:59 - Twitter] Dx  at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.BuildManager.basicBuild(BuildManager.java:321)
[2012-05-14 10:40:59 - Twitter] Dx  at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.BuildManager.build(BuildManager.java:396)
[2012-05-14 10:40:59 - Twitter] Dx  at org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.Project$1.run(Project.java:618)
[2012-05-14 10:40:59 - Twitter] Dx  at org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.Workspace.run(Workspace.java:2344)
[2012-05-14 10:40:59 - Twitter] Dx  at org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.Project.internalBuild(Project.java:597)
[2012-05-14 10:40:59 - Twitter] Dx  at org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.Project.build(Project.java:124)
[2012-05-14 10:40:59 - Twitter] Dx  at com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.project.ProjectHelper.doFullIncrementalDebugBuild(ProjectHelper.java:1000)
[2012-05-14 10:40:59 - Twitter] Dx  at com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.launch.LaunchConfigDelegate.launch(LaunchConfigDelegate.java:147)
[2012-05-14 10:40:59 - Twitter] Dx  at org.eclipse.debug.internal.core.LaunchConfiguration.launch(LaunchConfiguration.java:854)
[2012-05-14 10:40:59 - Twitter] Dx  at org.eclipse.debug.internal.core.LaunchConfiguration.launch(LaunchConfiguration.java:703)
[2012-05-14 10:40:59 - Twitter] Dx  at org.eclipse.debug.internal.ui.DebugUIPlugin.buildAndLaunch(DebugUIPlugin.java:928)
[2012-05-14 10:40:59 - Twitter] Dx  at org.eclipse.debug.internal.ui.DebugUIPlugin$8.run(DebugUIPlugin.java:1132)
[2012-05-14 10:40:59 - Twitter] Dx  at org.eclipse.core.internal.jobs.Worker.run(Worker.java:54)
[2012-05-14 10:40:59 - Twitter] Dx 1 error; aborting
[2012-05-14 10:40:59 - Twitter] Conversion to Dalvik format failed with error 1
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems you have the same library already included, please check all references to android libraries and check you have all jar libs included only once.

Answer (score 0):

This may be due to the "annotations.jar" file.Please check with following link and it may solve your bugs.

[Missing annotations.jar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10061986/missing-annotations-jar)