# importing NotNull or Nullable and Android Studio won't compile

Tags: java, gradle, android-studio

When I add @NotNull or @Nullable annotations to a parameter Android Studio automatically helps me with adding /lib/annotations.jar and importing

```
import org.jetbrains.annotations.NotNull
import org.jetbrains.annotations.Nullable;
```

But after this, the project won't compile. If I also remove the annotations but keep the import statements the project still won't compile. **But** if I remove the import statements for NotNull and Nullable the project compiles *fine*!

Android Studio gives a generic error:

```
Gradle: 
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':Bugtester:compileDebug'.
> Compilation failed; see the compiler error output for details.

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
```

Running `gradlew compileDebug` from cmd gives a slight hint:

```
:Bugtester:compileDebug FAILED

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':Bugtester:compileDebug'.
> Cannot find System Java Compiler. Ensure that you have installed a JDK (not just a JRE) and configured your JAVA_HOME system variable to point to the according directory.

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

BUILD FAILED
```

So I checked my environment variables and they are set as:

```
JAVA_HOME=C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre7
JDK_HOME=C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_21\
```

Anyone got any idea for this? (I'm new to both java and android programming)

Comment: I'm not familiar with gradle, but you should probably add a dependency on `annotations.jar` to `build.gradle`. Something like `dependencies { compile files('full/path/to/annotations.jar') }`

Comment: Thanks, this fixed the issue! I thought adding the dependency was what android studio did automatically when I first wrote @NotNull and it wanted me to add something.

Comment: You can find explanation for this behavior here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16622410/how-do-i-add-a-library-project-to-the-android-studio-and-use-itsome-asked-dont/16683375#16683375

Comment: @vmironov if you add this as an answer I can accept it.

Answer (score 82, accepted):

I guess, the right way is using original JetBrains library from MavenCentral repository in your build.gradle dependencies (latest available version in this example):

```
dependencies {
    implementation 'com.intellij:annotations:+@jar'
    ...
}
```

Comment: `implementation` is used instead of `compile` in newer versions

Comment: I use implementation 'org.jetbrains:annotations:16.0.2' -- for gradle-5.1.1, its works for me.

Comment: Complete newb here -> Android 4, this did not work for me even after resync gradle and rebuild project.  I still get red errors.

Comment: removing this Line implementation 'org.jetbrains:annotations:15.0' from my build.gradle file solved my problem.

Answer (score 49):

You can also use android's own `@NonNull` & `@Nullable`:

- Add the following to **build.gradle**:

  ```
  dependencies {
      ...
      // For @Nullable/@NonNull
      compile 'com.android.support:support-annotations:+'
  }
  ```
- Go to **File** / **Setting** → **Project Settings** → **Inspections** and search for "nullable".

  In **Constant conditions & exceptions** and **@NotNull/@Nullable problems**, click **Configure annotations** and select Android's annotations.

  You may also want to check out **Suggest @Nullable annotations…** under **Constant conditions & exceptions**, or possibly tweak other options.

Comment: Your answer has solved my problem. Just one thing: The "Avoid using + in version number" warning is shown... i have set my version like this: 
`compile 'com.android.support:support-annotations:23.1.1'`

Comment: Was that supposed to be on Mac Android Studio -> Preferences, but then I can't find Project Settings nor Inspections.  I am on Android Studio 4.

Answer (score 13):

For using Android support anotation like - @Nullable, @NonNull etc.. In your project must be imported android support annotations library. Just **add this line to dependensies** in gradle file

`dependencies {
    compile 'com.android.support:support-annotations:+'
}`

And **import package** to class. 

For using @Nullable annotation:

```
import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
```

For @NonNull

```
import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
```

More info you can find here [Android developers](https://developer.android.com/studio/write/annotations.html)

Answer (score 8):

Just import **androidx.annotation.Nullable** for that purpose

Comment: Thanks! As of today, this is the easiest change

Comment: Not sure whether it's easier than other options but it seems to be the best today; the current way the functionality is exposed. And need to add to build.gradle dependencies "implementation 'androidx.annotation:annotation:1.6.0'" or something like that.

Answer (score 6):

At the moment, there is no NonNull/Nullable annotations in the Android API or in the support library. You also cannot use the IntelliJ one since they are not on the compilation classpath when building with Gradle.

However, you can easily create your own. It's very simple:

```
@Documented
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.CLASS)
@Target({METHOD,PARAMETER,LOCAL_VARIABLE,FIELD})
public @interface NonNull {
}
```

Once this is down, you can configure IntelliJ (or Android Studio) to recognize this one (and the matching `@Nullable`) to be the default annotation used for Null-checks.

To do this, go in the IntelliJ preferences, under `Inpections`, and then find the `@NotNull/@Nullable problems` entry under `Probable Bugs` in the inspection tree.

Select the item, and in the bottom right you'll have a button to "Configure Annotations". This will allow you set your own annotations as the one intelliJ will use for this inspection.

Comment: upvote because this tip does not need any additional third party libraries

Answer (score 5):

In 2015, you would have used annotations from **android.support.annotation** package. I am just not sure when they added them as in the [docs](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/annotation/NonNull.html) there isn't that typical sentence "Added in API level X" and I don't feel like reading blogs, etc. >]

```
import android.support.annotation.NonNull;

...

public void fooFighter(@NonNull Object honeyBunny){
   ...
}
```

Comment: Gone are the nowadays of 2015, in the nowadays of 2019, use **androidx.annotation:annotation:1.x.x** :P

Comment: _Smoooooooth!_ +1  ;)

Answer (score 4):

I am facing that problem for **gradle-5.1.1** - **Android Studio 3.4** and the error like that - *Compilation failed; see the compiler error output for details. Execution failed for task ':app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.* etc. In this case I use

```html
implementation 'org.jetbrains:annotations:16.0.2'
```

and above all error will be clear.

Comment: I wish this worked.  But like everything else, I can't seem to shake this error.

Answer (score 0):

The best way is to use the maven dependency

1. set the repository path, by adding

   ```
   repositories {
       maven {
           url "https://repository.jboss.org/nexus/content/repositories/thirdparty-releases"
       }
   }
   ```
2. add the dependency

   ```
   dependencies {
       compile 'org.jetbrains:annotations:7.0.2'
   }
   ```
3. PROFIT!

Answer (score 0):

For Maven add dependency:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.jetbrains</groupId>
    <artifactId>annotations</artifactId>
    <version>16.0.1</version>
</dependency>
```