# ADT bundle missing proguard

Tags: android, eclipse, eclipse-adt

I've downloaded the latest version of ADT from website for Linux 64bit. Everything works but I can't use Proguard because under SDK/tools folder the proguard folder is missing! I've got currently installed the SDK Tools rev. 23. Any help? Can someone share the proguard folder?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Fail to find annotations.jar after updating to ADT 23](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24438748/fail-to-find-annotations-jar-after-updating-to-adt-23)

Comment: It's been raised as an issue - code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=72419