# Annotations missing LIB

Tags: android, annotations

Have looked around alot here.
Have tried alot of diffrent soultions but none of them works.

I have a error message saying

```
The container 'Android Dependencies' references non existing library 'C:\Users\Kodare\Documents\Development\sdk\tools\support\annotations.jar'
```

Then when I'll try to add annotations.jar (downloaded) one it says

```
CropImageView cannot be resolved to a type
```

Anyone know how I possible could fix this?

Answer (score 0):

If possible, change your build target to API16

In Eclipse: Right click on project -> properties -> Android and there choose API 16 or more

Also, not sure where did you download `annotations.jar` from but take a look at this answer and try following instructions in there: https://stackoverflow.com/a/24460968/3702187

Comment: The CropImageView is still there when I take that annotations and switch to API 17.