# Proguard Error after updating ADT 23

Tags: android, eclipse, proguard

I am trying to export a project. I have enabled Proguard for the project. I am getting a problem Invalid Proguard configuration file path and directory is shown.

This error is coming up after I updated my ADT 23. :(

Check the image below:

[image]

How can I fix this issue?

Answer (score 1):

Copy `proguard folder` from previous tools, and add in `~\Android-SDK\tools\<proguard>` there is problem in this version, you might also get [annotation.jar missing](https://stackoverflow.com/q/24438748/1008278)

Answer (score 0):

try updating to 23.0.1 (proguard was missing in v.23)

Answer (score 0):

This is a known, already [reported issue](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=72419). Try to update to just released 23.0.1.

Comment: Same issue was reported again. Start the issue on the tracker and add your message saying issue is not fixed yet. They are working on a next fix.

Answer (score 0):

Updating to 23.0.1 didn't work. I just downloaded Proguard directly from the below:

http://goo.gl/qThzGF

Copied it to the tools inside the SDK folder. I was able to export the apk without any issues...

Thanks!