# Wikitude missing annotations.jar

Tags: android, sdk, sample, wikitude

after importing Wikitude samples this message appear:
"The container 'Android Dependencies' references non existing library 'C:\Android Devepment\ADT Full x86\sdk\tools\support\annotations.jar'"
In other projects i didn't received this error, I have full version of ADT with install all things, where is main problem!?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that your problem is not related to the Wikitude SDK but generally to your working environment (Eclipse, Android Plugin, Android SDK Version).
Please see at: [Missing annotations.jar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10061986/missing-annotations-jar) and check if that solves your issue.

Hope that helps,
Markus